# How to get value of a dynamically created form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, ecmascript-6

here is below 3 form which generated dynamically in my code.

```
<form id="abc">
   <input id="link" value ="aa">name
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="abc">
   <input id="link" value ="bb">name
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="abc">
   <input id="link" value ="cc">name
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in js i was trying to fetch input value of form which is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#abc').submit(function (e) {
    var bla = $('#link').val();
    alert(bla);     
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

But whichever form i submit i always got 1st form input value. I know i am doing this thing wrong can you explain how can i get input value of the form which is submit currently.

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should always be unique.In your case  use `class` as a common selector

Here are the changes

**HTML**

id is replaced with class

```
<form class="abc">
  <input class="link" value="aa">name
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="abc">
  <input class="link" value="bb">name
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="abc">
  <input class="link" value="cc">name
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

using class selector & jquery `find` method to find an `input` with class `link`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.abc').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var bla = $(this).find('input.link').val();
    alert(bla);

  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gj6czkko/)

Comment: OP said the form is added dynamically, this won't work on dynamically added forms!

Answer (score 2):

`id` of element in `document` should be unique. Substitute `.className` for duplicate `.id` at `<form>`, `<input>` elements. Use event delegation to attach `submit` event for `form` elements having `.className` `"abc"`; use `jQuery()` with `".link"` selector and `context` set to `this` at event handler, chain `.val()` to get `.value` of current `<input>` element.

```js
// dynamic `html`
var html = `<form class="abc">
   <input class="link" value ="aa">name
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="abc">
   <input class="link" value ="bb">name
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="abc">
   <input class="link" value ="cc">name
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>`;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("submit", ".abc", function (e) {
    var bla = $(".link", this).val();
    alert(bla);     
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $("body").append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't you think the accepted answer is incorrect? since the form is dynamically added

Comment: @YogeshMistry Had not noticed. OP will notice when relying on result from event handler.

Comment: I don't think he will. Since he has already accepted the answer. How strange it is. People will stumble up on this question and see the accepted answer incorrect! :D

Comment: _"I don't think he will."_ If the form is actually dynamic, OP might notice. Though note, the pattern at accepted Answer should return expected result if `javascript` which attaches event to elements is appended to `document` after `html` is appended to `document`. Not clear from Answer or feedback from OP if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

While dealing with dynamically created form element, bind its event while taking `document` into context i.e. `$(document).on("event_name", 'dynamic_element', function(){ ... });`

So, below code shall work in your case.

```
$(document).on("submit", 'form.abc', function(){ 
    ... // you can get the form elements value here.
    var bla = $(this).find('.link').val();
    alert(bla);     
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Note:** Avoid using same IDs for multiple elements, use `class`es instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the $("form") submit event to handle this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function(e) { 
    var bla = $(this).find('#link').val();
    alert(bla);     
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Here is the working sample:https://jsfiddle.net/e7r14p3t/

Answer (score 0):

HTML `id`s should be used for only one element each. For multiple elements, you should use the `class` attribute, which can be selected in jQuery with $('.abc').

HTML:

```
<form class="abc">
    <input id="link" value ="aa">name
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="abc">
    <input id="link" value ="bb">name
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form class="abc">
    <input id="link" value ="cc">name
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.abc').submit(function (e) {
    var bla = $('#link').val();
    alert(bla);
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```